# SQL Services list disappeared when installed SQL Server Data Tools 2013

Tags: sql-server

When first tried to process a cube on SQL Server Data Tools I got the next error:

> A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running.

Then I went to SQL Server Configuration Manager to find that the SQL Server Services is empty, and before that I had all the services. After that I did `services.msc` to ensure I still having the services and set them in Automatic. I've already reinstalled everything and still having the issue.

I have installed SQL Server 2019 Developer and SQL Server Data Tools for visual Studio 2013.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried opening SQL Server Configuration as Admin?

Comment: Yep, and it's the same..

Comment: Sometimes, SQL Configuration has many version, look for c:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager*.mmc, maybe 1 could be the good one to use

Comment: Wew, you are right, thanks.